# How parentheis {} work in then of promise object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch, parentheses

I am using simple react component. Here is the code.

```
      import React from 'react';
      export default class UserProfile extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            posts: [],
            name: 'ALok'
          }
        }

    componentDidMount()
    {
      fetch ('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then (response => response.json())
      .then (res => this.setState({ posts : res}));

    }
    render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <h1>{this.state.posts.length}</h1>
      </div>
    )
    }
  }
```

This code works. 
But If I try to add multiple instruction at

```
componentDidMount()
  {
    fetch ('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then (response => response.json())
    .then (res => this.setState({ posts : res}));
```

to something like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch ('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then (response =>  { 
        // adding multiple line 
        response.json(); 
        console.log ('Custom Log');
        })
    .then (res => this.setState({ posts : res}));
}
```

It stop working. 
It gives an error

[Screen shot of the error in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t23LZ.png)

Comment: Those are *braces*, and this is nothing to do with then/promise. That's an *arrow function*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a promise as part of the promise chain. Other than that, the `{}` are just normal JS scoping, functional scoping in this case. You were implicitly returning `undefined` and that was being assigned to `res` in the next thenable and saved into state.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch ('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then (response =>  { 
        // adding multiple line
        console.log ('Custom Log');
        return response.json(); 
    })
    .then (res => this.setState({ posts : res}));
}
```